# Integration with exponential and trigonometric functions

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

> $$\int_0^\pi \frac{e^{-\sin x}}{e\sin x + e^{\sin x}}\,\mathrm dx $$

This does not seem to work out by simple substitutions. Any clues will be helpful.

Comment: Welcome to Math Stack Exchange. Write your questions clearly. Please use MathJax . See https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Is your integral supposed to be $$\int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{e^{-\sin(x)}}{e^{-\sin(x)}+e^{\sin(x)}}dx$$?

Comment: No its esinx as written.

Comment: Where did you come across this integral? I havent looked at it thoroughly but maybe complex analysis is required?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This integral doesn't have an elementary anti-derivative. The only anti-derivative for this function would be integrating a couple of taylor series.